# Hide EditText on Login dialog Android on XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-edittext

I want to hide an EditText form on login dialog Android app
Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <EditText android:id="@id/etUsername" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="@string/pref_provider_title_user_name" android:ems="10">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
    **<EditText android:id="@id/etPassword" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="@string/pref_provider_title_user_password" android:ems="10" android:inputType="textPassword" />**
    <EditText android:id="@id/etServer" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="@string/pref_provider_title_server" android:ems="10" />
    <TextView android:id="@id/tvInfo" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:ems="10" />
    <Button android:id="@id/btnOk" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/text_ok" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to hide the password and make fixed value if someone can help me

Comment: See the linked post then, if you're still stuck, please give a more clear description of what you are doing and what problem you are facing.

Answer (score -1):

In your java code:

> EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_id);
>   et.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Or

> et.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: You answer should help the user to solve their problems/issues in code. Not sure if something as above will be helpful to them. Please explain your code further so any one reading this post will be able to understand what you want him to change/fix.

Comment: @Syfer I think my answer is clear enough for an android developer :/